# toggle jquery button as checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to toggle a checkbox-button in Jquery.
assuming they are originally checkboxes, I tried

```
$("btn").attr('checked',true);
```

but did not function when the using checkbox as a button.

simply, I just want is to set the button below..

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

like the checkbox is checked in example:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/

--edit-- see the sample code..

```
<html><head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#check" ).button();//when not a button it works .. just uncomment it.
$( "#check" ).attr("checked",true);//??
});
</script></head><body>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" /><label for="check">Toggle</label>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Check answer here [http://jsfiddle.net/5RgK6/](http://jsfiddle.net/5RgK6/)

Answer (score 1):

`$("btn").attr('checked','checked');`

Also see [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify class or id... e.g: `$("#btn")`

Answer (score 0):

you missed the dot from selector :P

```
  $(".btn").attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: only if "btn" happens to be a class

Comment: no ... but sorry I edited it from $("#"+idd)..
it even didn't work with single selector $("#fv")

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(".btn").attr('checked',true);
```

As i can see you are missing `. or #`, depends upon whether `btn` is id or class

Answer (score 0):

sorry, that's a bug in jquery;
   http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7476